# Peer reviews Assign name in each row of column (D) from an array of names. If column C name = array name, go to next name in array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet where employees will peer review each other's records. I am stumped on how to assign records from an array of names without the names matching on columns (C) & (D)

- Column C and D can have duplicates of names
- Columns C and D cannot match
- Column D will populate with names from an array of names until the last row
- Loop through each row in column d and assign name from array empNames. The loop will restart once the last name in the array has been read.

[image: ![example]

Here is the code i have so far in getting an array of names.

```
Sub assign2ndQR()

Dim empNames As Variant, lWksIndex As Long
Dim LastRow As Integer

LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("employees").UsedRange.Rows.count
empNames = UniquesFromRange(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("employees").Range("A2:A" & LastRow))


'Loop through each row in column d and assign name from empNames.
'If column C & D match, go to next position and assign name




'debugging
If UBound(empNames) = -1 Then
    Debug.Print "no values found"
Else
    Debug.Print "got array of unique values"
End If

End Sub

Function UniquesFromRange(Rng As Range)

 Dim d As Object, c As Range, tmp
 Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
 For Each c In Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
   tmp = Trim(c.Value)
  If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
    If Not d.Exists(tmp) Then d.Add tmp, 1
 End If
 Next c
 UniquesFromRange = d.keys

End Function
```

Anything helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try.

```
Sub assign2ndQR()
    Dim empNames As Variant, lWksIndex As Long
    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Long
    Dim arrC, arrD, iIdx as Long
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("employees")
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        empNames = UniquesFromRange(.Range("A2:A" & LastRow))
        If UBound(empNames) > -1 Then
            iIdx = LBound(empNames) ' Starter index = 0
            ' Load names from Column C
            arrC = .Range(.[C1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Value
            ' Create an array to keep values of Column D
            arrD = arrC
            ' Loop through names of Column C
            For i = 1 To UBound(arrC)
                ' Name matching skip
                If empNames(iIdx) = arrC(i, 1) Then iIdx = iIdx + 1
                ' Assign name
                arrD(i, 1) = empNames(iIdx)
                iIdx = iIdx + 1
                ' Restart the index pointer
                If iIdx > UBound(empNames) Then iIdx = LBound(empNames)
            Next
            .Range("D:D").ClearContents
            .[d1].Resize(UBound(arrD), 1).Value = arrD
        End If
    End With
End Sub
Function UniquesFromRange(Rng As Range)
    Dim d As Object, c As Range, tmp
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
        tmp = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(tmp) > 0 And (Not d.Exists(tmp)) Then
            d.Add tmp, 1
        End If
    Next c
    UniquesFromRange = d.keys
End Function
```

Comment: Hi thanks it worked. Thanks for giving me insight on how to tackle this kind of problem. Copying the array length from C to D made sense. 

I had to move If iIdx > UBound(empNames) Then iIdx = LBound(empNames) to start the for loop as subscript was out of range and this statement would not trigger.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Another option is move it after `iIdx = iIdx + 1`.